# Div transform into editor instance

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want jaqury or ajax method for Div transform into editor instance.
When i will click into div then it will change in to editor where i can change the div context and use all functions of editor.
I am not getting any soution for this using jquery or ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ajaxline.com/best-ajax-text-editors) you can find a nice list of Editors for what you want.
(i can recommend MarkItUp!, i'ts a very nice editor)